# Query efficiency

Tags: php, sql, mysql, database

```
$_query = 'UPDATE ' . TABLE_A1 . ' SET active=0 WHERE user_id IN ( ';
                foreach ($newUsers as $newUser) {
                    $_query.=$newUser. ' ,';
                }
                $_query = rtrim($_query, ',');
                $_query .=')';
```

Is this a performant way of editing multiple table entries at once? Are there faster ways?

thanks

Comment: There may be faster ways but we can't tell from what you show. Where does `$newUsers` come from? Maybe there is a mySQL-only way to specify what is a new user?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, this is very performant. I do not know of any faster way.

Answer (score 1):

The UPDATE is fine.
You can make your PHP a bit more elegant by using an `implode` instead of looping through that array.

i.e.:

```
$_query = 'UPDATE ' . TABLE_A1 . ' SET active=0 WHERE user_id IN (' . implode(',', $newUsers) . ');'
```

Answer (score 1):

You could add another contraint to the query, which could speed it up a tad more, but that depends on how you get your users...

If you have some users that are already "active=0", thou you could exclude them in the query by adding

.... where active<>0 and user_id in (...

This will prevent updates on fields that already have the correct value. I had a similar query on a system oncce, and it was updating millions of records which alreay contained the correct information...